# export python dictionary with list as value to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

i have two list and combined these 2 list to a dictionary:

```
ip = ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3", " 4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5", "6.6.6.6", "7.7.7.7"]
name = ["ip0", "ip2", "ip2", "ip3", "ip3", "ip3"]

{'ip2': "['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']", 'ip3': "[' 4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6']", 'ip0': "['1.1.1.1']"}
```

i want to export this Dictionary to CSV file
key is in one cell,  the paired value should also be in next cell and there should be mulitple lines in this cell for ip address.
example:

```
ip2 2.2.2.2
    3.3.3.3
```

how should i do it?

combine two list config:

```
k = list(zip(name, ip))
d = {}
for (x,y) in k:
    if x in d:
        d[x] = d[x] +","+ y 
    else:
        d[x] = y
```

Comment: `"7.7.7.7"` does not appear in the final dictionary. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: sorry, just copied extra IP. let me edit my questions. thank you

Comment: i used python version 2.7. yes, you are right, i changed the list to string when i combined these 2 lists to dictionary. do you have the scirpt to combin 2 lists to a dictionary without change list to string?.

Comment: Your output requirements are not well expressed. Is it really a valid csv format to have one row over multiple lines? If you could express your required output for your provided input values (`ip` and `name`) it would make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I see what you meant. Here is an example of an updated answer:

```
ip = ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3", "4.4.4.4", "5.5.5.5", "6.6.6.6", "7.7.7.7"]
name = ["ip0", "ip2", "ip2", "ip3", "ip3", "ip3"]

# Create dictionary
# We use setdefault to list ([]) here to be able to append values to list
# if it does not exist yet.
#d = {}
#for x,y in list(zip(name,ip)):
#    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)


# But to use your example we can use this small modification:
k = list(zip(name, ip))
d = {}
# Create dictionary
for (x,y) in k:
    if x in d:
        d[x] += [y]
    else:
        d[x] = [y]

# Output dictionary
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    for k,v in d.iteritems(): # d.items() if py3
        for ind,item in enumerate(v):
            if ind == 0:
                f.write("{},{}\n".format(k,item))
            else:
                f.write(",{}\n".format(item))
```

---

"output.csv":

```
ip0,1.1.1.1
ip2,2.2.2.2
,3.3.3.3
ip3,4.4.4.4
,5.5.5.5
,6.6.6.6
```

Dictionary now looks like this:

```
 {'ip0': ['1.1.1.1'],
 'ip2': ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3'],
 'ip3': ['4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6']}
```

Comment: thank you answer my question, but i tried it the reuslt is not correct:ip2 [ip2 'ip2 2ip2 .ip2 2ip2 .ip2 2ip2 .ip2 2ip2 'ip2  ip2  ip2 'ip2 3ip2 .ip2 3ip2 .ip2 3ip2 .ip2 3ip2 'ip2 ]ip3 [ip3 'ip3  ip3 4ip3 .ip3 4ip3 .ip3 4ip3 .ip3 4ip3 'ip3  ip3  ip3 'ip3 5ip3 .ip3 5ip3 .ip3 5ip3 .ip3 5ip3 'ip3  ip3  ip3 'ip3 6ip3 .ip3 6ip3 .ip3 6ip3 .ip3 6ip3 'ip3 ]ip0 [ip0 'ip0 1ip0 .ip0 1ip0 .ip0 1ip0 .ip0 1ip0 'ip0 ]

Comment: still not work properly:ip2 2.2.2.2
 ip2
ip3  4.4.4.4
 ip3
 ip3
ip0 1.1.1.1

Comment: @yangyu sorry, one thing was not removed updated again

Comment: i used python version 2.7. yes, you are right, i changed the list to string when i combined these 2 lists to dictionary. do you have the scirpt to combin 2 lists to a dictionary without change list to string?

Comment: @yangyu yes there are plenty ways to do this. But there isn't one script that does everything but rather one script that does one thing. What I mean is: you need to explain more how you got those IP numbers and how to distrubute them.

Comment: @Antor, Thank you help me working on this script . I updated my join list script, and your outscprit does not work .

Comment: @yangyu no worries, if you had provided the info you did now from the start you get help faster. Anyway see my updated answer :)

Comment: @yangyu no problem. Consider marking this as an answer! :)